# Delay between a loop using javascript or jquery for a multiple number counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter, odometer

I have been trying to create a number counter using javascript and jquery. I want 2 counters where one depends on the other. 
I want a counter to increment from 0-2000 with an interval of 100 milliseconds between increments. and whenever one counter reaches an multiple of 200(num=200 or num=400 or num=600...) the other counter increments by one. The result expected is a counter goin from 0-2000 and another going from 0-10 in the same amount of time.

This a code snippet I have failed to get the result with:

html code:

```
<span id="counter" >0</span>
<span id="counter2" >0</span>
```

javascript code:

```
function counting(){
     var cc=0;
     for(var c=0;c<2000;c++){
        if((c % 200) === 0){
         $('#counter2').text(cc+1);
        }
        else{
         setTimeout(function(){$('#counter').text(c);},100);           
        }  
     }
}
```

Please help me out with any javascript or jquery solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setInterval` is better suited here. Also, you should increment `cc` by `1` and store it in `cc` itself.

```js
function counting() {
  var cc = 0,
    c = 1;

  var int = setInterval(function() {
    $('#counter').text(c);

    if (c % 200 === 0) {
      cc += 1;
      $('#counter2').text(cc);
    }

    if (c >= 2000) {
      clearInterval(int);
    }

    c += 1;
  }, 1);
}

counting();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="counter">0</span>
<span id="counter2">0</span>
```

I've modified the interval to 1ms for this demo. You may change it as per your requirements.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for the swift response and minimal code! :D

Answer (score 1):

Best to use `setInterval` with conditions inside the interval function, followed by a `clearInterval` at the end. No need for jQuery:

```js
const counter = document.querySelector('#counter');
const counter2 = document.querySelector('#counter2');

let count = 0;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  count++;
  counter.textContent = count;
  if (count % 200 === 0) counter2.textContent = count / 200;
  if (count === 2000) clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
```

```html
<span id="counter" >0</span>
<span id="counter2" >0</span>
```

A sped-up version:

```js
const counter = document.querySelector('#counter');
const counter2 = document.querySelector('#counter2');

let count = 0;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  count++;
  counter.textContent = count;
  if (count % 200 === 0) counter2.textContent = count / 200;
  if (count === 2000) clearInterval(interval);
}, 10);
```

```html
<span id="counter" >0</span>
<span id="counter2" >0</span>
```